# Integrating MVC3 to webforms - MVC Routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have followed all steps on this link including web.config changes and adding required assemblies.
[ASP.Net and Webforms in Harmony](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38778/ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-MVC-in-Harmony#heading0007)
I have installed MVC3 into the webforms project and Implemented a controller and registered its routes in Application_Start method of Global.asax.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here is the controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Hello from Home controller";
        return View();
    }

}
```

I am trying to call its action (i.e /Home/Index) but getting 404 Not Found error.

Route registered for other .aspx form are working fine.

```
 routes.Add("Home", new Route("Home", new RoutingHandler("/Default.aspx")));
```

Everything is working fine but (Home/Index) is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding `Area` in your web project for example `MVC`. Then you need to register that `Area` in `Global` class in `Global.asax.cs` file's function `protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` function like below

`MVCAreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(RouteTable.Routes);`

Now add a controller for example `Home` and add a view say `Index`. Place a break point on Index action method and run your application. In url type ".../MVC/Home/Index" and the break point will got hit.